# How to share instance member among all instances of type

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have base class, many inherited classes and problem with my brains:

```
abstract class Base
{
    abstract Dictionary<string, string> X { get; }
    abstract Dictionary<string, string> Y { get; }
}

class A : Base
{
    override Dictionary<string, string> X { get; } = ... // different
    override Dictionary<string, string> Y { get; } = ... // same for all instances of A
}

class B : Base { ... }
```

I see what `A.Y` will be *same* for all instances of `A`, `B.Y` will be same for all instances `B`, etc., using `new Dictionary` for `Y` is kinda ... stupid, unnecessary allocation of memory.

How do I share `Y` among all instances? My brains want to make it `static` and inherit.

`X` and `Y` are never changed (probably should be read-only dictionaries, but that's not a question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Y`'s instance private static in the derived class, and return it in the getter:

```
class A : Base {
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> sharedY = ...
    override Dictionary<string, string> X { get; } = ... // different
    override Dictionary<string, string> Y {
        get => sharedY
    }
}
```

**Note:** I assume that shared dictionaries would be populated once, never modified again. Otherwise you are in for a lot of trouble, especially in concurrent environments.

Comment: Oh, so easy? Thanks.

Comment: Note a static `Dictionary<...>` is almost certainly a terrible idea - especially when exposed on the public API like this; that's a threading nightmare /cc @Sinatr

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree. I added a note explaining my assumption about OP's use of the shared dictionary.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, no worry, I don't need thread-safety and dictionaries content indeed will not be changed. Your answer fits perfectly. It was a short-circuit in my brains what `static` should be in base class. If my question is asked after 16:00, then it's likely a *stupid* one ;)